# C++ Sorting Indices in new array

Tags: c++

Let's say I have an array A = {6.5, 2.2, 5.6, 7.1}. How would I go about placing the ordered indices of array in a new array, without changing the original contents of A? So, B would equal to {1, 2, 0, 3}.

Edit: My current code just orders the original array itself.

```
int main(){
    int temp;
    const int N = 6;
    int arr[N] = {6.5, 2.2, 5.6, 7.1};
    int sortedIndex[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
         for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++){
             if (arr[j] < arr[i]){
                 temp = arr[i]
                 arr[i] = arr[j]
                 arr[j] = temp; }
    {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not modify the original contest of A ;)

Comment: Sorry, new to the forum. Will post.

Comment: @JDoe: Note that Stackoverflow is *not* a forum. It's a community effort to build a high-quality knowledge base of programming problems and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a custom comparator:

```
std::array<double, 4> A = {6.5, 2.2, 5.6, 7.1};

std::array<int,4> indices;
std::iota(begin(indices), end(indices), 0); // initialize the index array

// sort with custom comparator, that compares items not by their own value
// but by the value of the corresponding entries in the original array.
std::sort(begin(indices), end(indices),
          [&A](int lhs, int rhs) { return A[lhs] < A[rhs]; });

std::copy(begin(indices), end(indices), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: Is there a simpler algorithm to do this, perhaps using a for loop?

Comment: @JDoe _Effective STL_ item 43: "Prefer algorithm calls to hand-written loops." You could do this with a `for` loop but you shouldn't. The code you show in your post is a case in point; You've implemented 'bubble sort' such that it can't be reused. It's better to spend some time implementing a better sorting algorithm and then to make it reusable. Better yet is to let someone else do it and just use their work. You could replace those nested loops with a simple and readable `sort(begin(arr), end(arr))`.

Comment: @JDoe If you want to use manual loops anyway, all you have to do is take the idea from my answer and plug it into your existing code: sort the index array instead of the original array, and modify the comparison logic so that instead of directly comparing entries in the array you're sorting, you compare the corresponding entries in the original array.